# How to break out of a nested until loop, without affecting the for loop its initially in

Tags: perl, loops

Got a very technical coding problem with perl. Basically I am search for some specific DNA sequences.

```
my $seq = '...';
my @dna = split //, $seq;
my $amount = scalar @dna; 

for my $index (0 .. $amount - 1){
    if ($dna[$index] eq 'A' and $dna[$index+1] eq 'T' and 
         $dna[$index+2] eq 'G' and $dna[$index+3] eq 'C'
    ) {
        do {
            print $dna[$index++];
        } until ($dna[$index] eq 'C' and $dna[$index+1] eq 'C' and $dna[$index+2] eq'G')
    }
}
```

The problem is,is that the "until" portion is in an infinite loop. I am getting all my sequences, but for some reason the until loop wont stop looping. I have tried

`until ($dna[$index] eq 'C' and $dna[$index+1] eq 'C' and $dna[$index+2] eq 'G' ){last;}`

But that breaks out of the *"for"* loop.
Is there a way to break out of *do-until* loop without breaking the  *for* loop?

Comment: they code you have posted does not compile, please provide the actual code you are working with.

Comment: Not the issue, but you shouldn't be modifying `$index`

Comment: The loop terminates OK when the sequence contains CCG.

Answer (score 3):

### Case 1

```
my $seq = 'xxxxxATGCyyyyyCCGzzzzz';  # Ouputs ATGCyyyyy
```

When every `ATGC` is followed by a `CCG`, your code works.

### Case 2

```
my $seq = 'xxxxxATGCyyyyy';  # Infinite loop
```

When there's no `CCG` following a `ATGC`, you keep incrementing `$index` past the end of `@dna`, causing an infinite loop.

### Case 3

```
my $seq = 'wwwwwATGCxxxxxATGCyyyyyCCGzzzzz';  # Ouputs ATGCxxxxxATGCyyyyy and ATGCyyyyy
```

You start looking for another match where the previous match *started* rather than where it *ended*, so you can end up with overlapping matches. This is partly due to a bad assumption the loop will continue from the value to which you changed `$index`.

### Solution

```
my $seq = '...';
my @seq = split //, $seq;
my $seq_len = @seq;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $seq_len-7; ++$i) {
    if (   $seq[$i+0] eq 'A'
        && $seq[$i+1] eq 'T'
        && $seq[$i+2] eq 'G'
        && $seq[$i+3] eq 'C'
     ) {
        my $start = $i;
        $i += 4;
        for (; $i < $seq_len-3; ++$i) {
            if (   $seq[$i+0] eq 'C'
                && $seq[$i+1] eq 'C'
                && $seq[$i+2] eq 'G'
            ) {
                my $end = $i;
                print(join('', @seq[$start .. $end-1]), "\n");
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`substr` simplifies things.

```
my $seq = '...';
my $seq_len = length($seq);
for (my $i = 0; $i < $seq_len-7; ++$i) {
    if (substr($seq, $i, 4) eq 'ATGC') {
        my $start = $i;
        $i += 4;
        for (; $i < $seq_len-3; ++$i) {
            if (substr($seq, $i, 3) eq 'CCG') {
                my $end = $i;
                print(substr($seq, $start, $end-$start), "\n");
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But regular expressions simply things much further.

```
my $seq = '...';
while ($seq =~ / ( ATGC .*? ) (?= CCG ) /xsg) {
    print("$1\n");
}
```

If you wanted to output the remainder of the string when there is no `CCG`, you can use the following:

```
my $seq = '...';
while ($seq =~ / ( ATGC (?:(?! CCG ).)* ) /xsg) {
    print("$1\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [perlsyn](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn)

> For "last", you have to be more elaborate:
>
> ```
> LOOP: { 
>     do {
>         last if $x = $y**2;
>         # do something here
>     } while $x++ <= $z;
> }
> ```

If the sequence doesn't contain `CCG` somewhere later than `ATGC`, the loop won't terminate. Add `or $index == $#dna` to the condition.

Comment: The OP problem asked why the termination condition of the until loop is never met. This does not relate to that problem.

Comment: @ikegami: That's not how I understood **Is there a way to break out of do-until loop without breaking the for loop** ? But not being native English speaker, I might be wrong.

Comment: Unforunately I have used the `last` statement in multiple variations. When I had a `LINE: For (){}`  I had a `last LINE if $index == $amount;`, but that failed to get rid of the infinite loop.

Comment: @user3802685: [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) would help a lot.

Comment: @choroba, That doesn't contradict what I said. He does indeed want to exit the loop that never exits. And this is done by fixing the broken termination condition.

Comment: @choroba, For a SSCCE, just replace `my $seq = '...';` with `my $seq = 'xxxxxATGCyyyyyzzzzz';`

Answer (score 0):

Although I definitely endorse @ikegami's regular expression-based approach, let's try to salvage what you have.  Some specific issues:

- Use the C-style for/foreach loop so that adjustments to $index carry over to the outer loop
- You can't use `last` or `next` directly in a `do {} until ()` or `do {} while ()` loop -- these aren't `while ()` or `until ()` loops, they are `do` constructs and these keywords don't apply.  See some of the other answers with respect to wrapping the `do` construct in a one-shot loop to make these keywords viable.
- You need to deal with the possiblity of running out of data before finding the things you're looking for.

Here's my rework of your code to get it to run and clear @ikegami's test hurdles:

```
use constant { START => 'ATGC', STOP => 'CCG' };
use constant { START_LENGTH => length(START), STOP_LENGTH => length(STOP) };

my $sequence = 'wwwwwATGCxxxxxATGCyyyyyCCGzzzzz';
my @dna = split //, $sequence;

for (my $index = 0; $index < @dna - START_LENGTH; $index++) {

    if (join('', @dna[$index .. $index + START_LENGTH - 1]) eq START) {
        do {
            print $dna[$index++];
        } until ($index > $#dna or ($index < @dna - STOP_LENGTH and join('', @dna[$index .. $index + STOP_LENGTH - 1]) eq STOP));

        print("\n");
    }
}
```

(Yes, the `$#dna` messes with the SO formatter as it thinks it's introducing a comment.  I'm sure someone knows how to fix this and will edit this answer accordingly.)